# Statsmodel Probplot Tick customization

Tags: python, matplotlib, statsmodels

I've created a cumulative probability plot with StatsModels in Python, but there are way too many ticks on the axis.
[image: Too many xticks]

I want there to be only be tick marks at 0.1, 10, 50, 90, 99, and 99.9. Anyone know how to make this work? I tried using the code below but it only gives me the first n number of ticks, making it pretty useless (See figure below.)

[image: Too few ticks]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import statsmodels.api as sm

csv = pd.read_csv('cumProbMaxData.csv')  
data = csv.values.tolist()

flat_list = [item for sublist in data for item in sublist]
fig,ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.array(flat_list)
pp_x = sm.ProbPlot(x, fit=True)
figure = pp_x.probplot(exceed=False, ax=ax, marker='.', color='k', markersize=12)

plt.xlabel('Cumulative Probability (%)')
plt.ylabel('Maximum CO$_2$ Flux (g m$^-$$^2$ d$^-$$^1$)')
tick_spacing=5
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MaxNLocator(tick_spacing))

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you try using `plt.xticks`? You can find some examples [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html?highlight=matplotlib%20pyplot%20xticks#matplotlib.pyplot.xticks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Statsmodels `ProbPlot` plots the data in their real units. It is only the axes ticks which are then changed as to show some percentage value. This is in general bad style but of course you have to live with it if you want to use `ProbPlot`.

A solution for the problem of showing less ticks on such a plot which uses a `FixedLocator` and `FixedFormatter` would be to subsample the shown ticks. The ticklabels you want to show are at indices `locs = [0,3,6,10,14,17,20]` (you want to show the ticklabel 0, 3, 6, etc.).
You can use this list to select from the shown ticks only those in the list as shown below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm

x = np.random.randn(200)

fig,ax = plt.subplots()

pp_x = sm.ProbPlot(x, fit=True)
pp_x.probplot(exceed=False, ax=ax, marker='.', color='k', markersize=12)

locs = [0,3,6,10,14,17,20]
ax.set_xticklabels(np.array(ax.xaxis.get_major_formatter().seq)[locs])
ax.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks()[locs])

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]